# Setting several elements to a fixed position

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a survey, when the user answers he gets the percentage of each answer with horizontals bars.

My problem is that at the moment this looks like that (== are bars):

- Answer A : ======= 50%
- Answer The Answer B === 25%
- Answer C Blabla === 25%

I would like to have all my bars that start at the same point.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="bloc-result">
Answer A <div class="survey_bar" style="height:15px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; display: inline-block; width:200px; color:white; background:#4AB4E6;" ;=""></div>50%<br>
```

Answer B and C are alike.

I would like to have the CSS proprety that solve my problem. I checked the position "absolute" but this sounds like 0% responsive and good to use.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle example? Or link to your website

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is what I'm aiming for : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=147288lol.png

Comment: @Paulie_D Actually my code is pretty useless because this is a general question but I thought that someone would ask for it.

Comment: Looks like you need a `table`.

Comment: Ah that might be a good idea ! There is no simple way using some css proprieties to get what I would like ?

Comment: It would be great, if you could provide jsfiddle link. Could help you using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
foreach($aData['Resultat'] as $iKey => $aVal) {
      $sHtml = '<div class="row">
                  <div class="cell">'.$aVal['REPONSE_LIB'].'</div>
                  <div class="cell">
                    <div class="barre_sondage" style="...blah blah..."></div>'.round($aVal['RESULTAT'],2).'%
                  </div>
                </div>';
      echo $sHtml;
}
```

and CSS:

```
.row{
  display: table-row;
}
.cell{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

i also recomend you to wrap whole thing into div with `display: table;`

EDIT:
you can just wrap answer with element with `display: inline-block` and fixed width too, but you will loose responsiveness

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is wrap the label in another tag so you can set the width for it.
here's an example:

```css
     .label {
      width: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
     }
     .bar {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 20px;
      background: black;
     }
     .pcent {
      display: inline-block;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="bloc-result">
        <div>
            <div class="label">Answer A</div>
            <div class="bar" style="width:50px;"></div>
            <div class="pcent">50%</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="label">Answer B</div>
            <div class="bar" style="width:30px;"></div>
            <div class="pcent">30%</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="label">Answer C</div>
            <div class="bar" style="width:20px;"></div>
            <div class="pcent">20%</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see each row and each element in that row has it's own element so you can do fine tuning on the design more easily.

Also, Here's a jsFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zd654roh/

Comment: Thank you for this great exemple.